# Expand Transition is not smooth

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a problem with strange behavior for expand transition. Transition is not smooth for some reason. It stops for a moment before disappearing - just like:

[image: Not smooth transition]

Template is as simple as

```html
<template>
  <v-expand-transition>
    <v-alert
      v-if="visible"
      prominent
      type="error">
      <v-row align="center">
        <v-col class="grow">
          {{message}}
        </v-col>
        <v-col class="shrink">
          <v-btn @click="invoke">{{button}}</v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-alert>
  </v-expand-transition>
</template>
```

How to fix it? 
I'm on latest stable chrome for windows (83.0.4103.61 x64)

Comment: Do you use `padding-top` or `padding-bottom` within the element? Depending on the box model you are using (`box-sizing`), the height does not include the padding of the element. So, if you have a height of 20px and padding of 10px, the box has actually a height of 40px. The transition however only shrinks the `height` attribute from 20px to 0px. Then, the element is taken out of the DOM after the animation (and it disappears).

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 No. Nothing. Code for alert is taken from documentation

Comment: The content (button, text) is therefore absolutely positioned within the box? Or positioned with flexbox? It would help if you shared your complete CSS of this element.

Comment: The class `.v-alert` which is on the alert element of the Vuetify documentation has a padding of 16px. Could you try to wrap the element which is going to be shrinked into a `<div>`, just for testing purposes?

Comment: You can easily reproduce this behavior with the DevTools, if you just set the height of the alert element to 0px. It still has a visible height of 32px just because of the padding.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3: Lol, ok, that helped if v-if is applied to this new div instead of on alert

Comment: Okay, great. It's just because the transition actually just decreases the CSS height of the element and finally removes the element. In a wrapper `<div>` this should not occur because there is no padding (it takes the actual height of the content).

Comment: You helped me a lot. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ssc-hrep3 mentioned in comments the code should look like:

```html
  <v-expand-transition>
    <div v-if="visible">
      <v-alert
        prominent
        type="error">
```

And that's it